# Find and replace Google Sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to automate the find and replace function of (Ctrl+H) with a script linked to a button, the reason being is that on the sheet we use the replaced text is always "zold"+"original text" the sheet is a multi page log that would require find and replace on multiple sheets matching the exact text. I can set up a simple find and replace but cant seem to get it to work when referencing the active cell. any pointers would be appreciated.

here's what I have attempted, looking through the documentation I'm not sure how to get the current cell from 'getActiveRange' to be combined into the text that would then replace the search criteria.

```
function markOld() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder();
  .matchEntireCell(true)
  .matchCase(true)
  .matchFormulaText(false)
  .ignoreDiacritics(false)
  .replaceAllWith('zold'+.getActiveRange());
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some coding attempts are necessary for best results here.

Comment: I updated the original post to include the script I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming most of your code is correct...

```
function markOld() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let cell_value = sheet.getCurrentCell().getValue(); // Find value of current cell https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcurrentcell
  sheet.createTextFinder(cell_value) // <-- Removed the ';' and added cell_value
       .matchEntireCell(true)
       .matchCase(true)
       .matchFormulaText(false)
       .ignoreDiacritics(false)
       .replaceAllWith('zold' + cell_value);
}
```

Comment: thank you that was the exact fix I needed